# Arrange activities in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a splash screen in my project it opens first with intent filter. After that it opens the main activity. But i created new activity that should be opened next to splash screen how to do that?

I have created three activities for example splash screen, main activity, login screen, Splash screen first opens next to that i need to open the login screen next only main activity.

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_main_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WeatherApp">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: can you please put your splash screen code .

Comment: i thing my code help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve this. This is one of my way.

First, at your `AndroidManifest.xml`, make sure you make your `SplashActivity` becomes your `launcher`. Then, at the `onCreate` method for your `SplashActivity`, do some delay, checking some stuff, is this user login or not. Last, go to next activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name="company.com.ui.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
            finish();
        }
    },
    4000);
```

Comment: What is this piece of code trying to do?